# Angular 8 Intercept call to refresh token

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8, angular-http-interceptors, refresh-token

I am trying to refresh access token if current access token is expired.

I am sending multiple requests at one time and I want to make a kind of a queue, so other requests won't request refreshing token route.

I've googled some best practises and examples and found out the following solution for Angular 6 and rxjs v6, which is using BehaviourSubject and switchMaps. (please see attached code)

However I am using Angular 8 (8.1) and rxjs v6.4 and this solution does not work for me.

It simply does not reach `switchMap` in `this.authService.requestAccessToken().pipe`. (Tested using console.log)

However if I comment `return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe` and return `next.handle(request)` it reaches that switchMap, but my other requests are failed.

Do you know if anything has been changed or should I try doing this in another way?

- **TokenInterceptor**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
    import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
    import { switchMap, take, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
    @Injectable()
    export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
        private refreshTokenInProgress = false;
        private refreshTokenSubject: Subject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

        constructor(public authService: AuthService) { }
        intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

            const accessExpired = this.authService.isAccessTokenExpired();
            const refreshExpired = this.authService.isRefreshTokenExpired();

            if (accessExpired && refreshExpired) {
                return next.handle(request);
            }
            if (accessExpired && !refreshExpired) {
                if (!this.refreshTokenInProgress) {
                    this.refreshTokenInProgress = true;
                    this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);
                    return this.authService.requestAccessToken().pipe(
                        switchMap((authResponse) => {
                            this.authService.saveToken(AuthService.TOKEN_NAME, authResponse.accessToken);
                            this.authService.saveToken(AuthService.REFRESH_TOKEN_NAME, authResponse.refreshToken);
                            this.refreshTokenInProgress = false;
                            this.refreshTokenSubject.next(authResponse.refreshToken);
                            return next.handle(this.injectToken(request));
                        }),
                    );
                } else {
                    return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
                        filter(result => result !== null),
                        take(1),
                        switchMap((res) => {
                            return next.handle(this.injectToken(request))
                        })
                    );
                }
            }

            if (!accessExpired) {
                return next.handle(this.injectToken(request));
            }
        }

        injectToken(request: HttpRequest<any>) {
            const token = this.authService.getToken(AuthService.TOKEN_NAME);
            return request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

- **requestAccessToken**

```
    requestAccessToken(): Observable<any> {
        const refreshToken = this.getToken(AuthService.REFRESH_TOKEN_NAME);
        return this.http.post(`${this.basePath}/auth/refresh`, { refreshToken });
    }
```

---

### UPD 1

So I used these sources to write my interceptor:

- https://itnext.io/angular-tutorial-implement-refresh-token-with-httpinterceptor-bfa27b966f57 (Angular 4 solution, I believe it edpends on rxjs version)
- https://github.com/melcor76/interceptors/blob/master/src/app/interceptors/auth.interceptor.ts

### UPD 2

I've excluded `refresh` request from interceptor scope and now it's working
Thanks to @JBNizet

Comment: My guess is that the authService sends an http request to get a refreshed token. So this http request is intercepted by this interceptor. And since a refresh is in progress, the request used to get a refreshed token can't be sent until the token has been refreshed. You shouldn't filter the requests that try to refresh the token the same way as the other requests.

Comment: @JBNizet just excluded that request and seems that everything is working now, thanks a lot, you've made my day.
Sometimes we need a fresh look at our code.

Comment: You should answer your own question with an explanation and with the code used to fix it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've excluded refresh request from interceptor scope and now it's working.
I've made a temporary fix in order to see it's working in the fastest way.

Now my TokenInterceptor looks like:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, take, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    private refreshTokenInProgress = false;
    private refreshTokenSubject: Subject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

    constructor(public authService: AuthService) { }
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (request.url.indexOf('refresh') !== -1) {
            return next.handle(request);
        }

        const accessExpired = this.authService.isAccessTokenExpired();
        const refreshExpired = this.authService.isRefreshTokenExpired();

        if (accessExpired && refreshExpired) {
            return next.handle(request);
        }
        if (accessExpired && !refreshExpired) {
            if (!this.refreshTokenInProgress) {
                this.refreshTokenInProgress = true;
                this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);
                return this.authService.requestAccessToken().pipe(
                    switchMap((authResponse) => {
                        this.authService.saveToken(AuthService.TOKEN_NAME, authResponse.accessToken);
                        this.authService.saveToken(AuthService.REFRESH_TOKEN_NAME, authResponse.refreshToken);
                        this.refreshTokenInProgress = false;
                        this.refreshTokenSubject.next(authResponse.refreshToken);
                        return next.handle(this.injectToken(request));
                    }),
                );
            } else {
                return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
                    filter(result => result !== null),
                    take(1),
                    switchMap((res) => {
                        return next.handle(this.injectToken(request))
                    })
                );
            }
        }

        if (!accessExpired) {
            return next.handle(this.injectToken(request));
        }
    }

    injectToken(request: HttpRequest<any>) {
        const token = this.authService.getToken(AuthService.TOKEN_NAME);
        return request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks to @JBNizet

Comment: can you please with accessExpired how you implemented in auth service

Comment: I was also facing same issue , a lot of valuable time spent in it. Finally it is working fine now after excluding the "refresh" api. Thanks for your post.

Comment: Thank you for this. It helped me a lot!

Comment: @AntGrisha sir can you please share me isAccessTokenExpired function also?

Comment: @KapilSoni, sure, so basically I just save token's expiration time to localstorage (unix format) during login. and my isAccessTokenExpired function looks like
    return moment().utc().isAfter(moment.unix(parseInt( localStorage.getItem('EXP_TIME'))));

Comment: @AntGrisha ok sir and what is inside isRefreshTokenExpired?

Comment: @KapilSoni basically it contained the same thing, but that was applied to saved refresh token.

Answer (score 1):

@AntGrisha , thanks for posting the solution after correcting.Saved me lots of work. I have added error handling as well.Might help some beginner like me and so posting it here.I have used angular 9.1.5 version.

Should pipe in the request handler as below.

```
return next.handle(this.injectToken(req)).pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError)
```

Error handler function definition

```
injectToken(request: HttpRequest<any>) {
    const token = this.authService.getToken(AuthService.TOKEN_NAME);
    return request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    });
}
//Error handling function
handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse){
console.log('Error Occurred: '+error);
if(error.status==401){
  return throwError("Unauthorized!");
}
else{
return throwError(error);
 }
```