# Why does my angular Interceptor take old value of token from localstorage?

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

When I login API sends to me the ****token**** and ****token-life-time**** , when **token-life-time** is going to be end , I refresh my **token** by sending request to API and receive new token and new **refresh-token-time**.
When I refresh or navigate to another page (at the moment when **token-life-time** is over) my interceptor sends old value of token from `LocalStorage` and API gives me an error ***'Not correct token'*** when I again refresh or navigate to another page it sends correct token.
But it repeats when the **token-life-time** is going to be over as described above.
Here is my `token-interceptor.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { LoginService } from '../services/login.service';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private loginService: LoginService
  ) { }
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (
      this.loginService.isLogged
    ) {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('access-token');
      const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
      request = request.clone({ headers: headers });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

It takes token and send request to API.

I have the `login.service.ts` with login and refresh function .**Login function** put token value into the `LocalStorage` and **Refresh function** refreshes the token in `LocalStorage` if `isNeedToRefresh` var is true and it works well.

```
refresh(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.post(`${environment.auth}/refresh`, {
      token_hash: localStorage.getItem('refresh-token')
    }).pipe(
      map((res: any) => {
        if (res.access && res.refresh) {
          localStorage.setItem('access-token', res.access.hash);
          localStorage.setItem('expires-at-access', res.access.expires_at);
          localStorage.setItem('refresh-token', res.refresh.hash);
          localStorage.setItem('expires-at-refresh', res.refresh.expires_at);
          return true;
        } else {
          this.notificationService.error(res && res.result_descr || '');
          return false;
        }
      }),
      catchError(() => of(false))
    );
  }
```

Here is where I refresh the token in `login.component.ts`

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (this.loginService.isLogged) {
      if (this.loginService.isNeedToRefresh === true) {
        this.loginService.refresh().subscribe((res: boolean) => {
          if (res === true) {
            this.router.navigate(['']);
          }
        });
      } else if (this.loginService.isNeedToRefresh === false) {
        this.router.navigate(['']);
      }
    }
  }
```

Also I update my token in `app.component.ts`

```
ngOnInit() {
    $(document).on('click', '[href="#"]', e => e.preventDefault());

    this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
      if (val instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        if (!(val.url.indexOf('/login') === 0)) {
          this.authWatcher();
        }
      }
    });
  }

authWatcher() {
    if (this.loginService.isLogged) {
      if (this.loginService.isNeedToRefresh === true) {
        this.loginService.refresh().subscribe((refresh: boolean) => {
          if (refresh === false) {
            this.authModalRef = this.modalService.show(this.staticModal, { backdrop: 'static' });
          } else {
            this.loginService.checkToken().subscribe((check: boolean) => {
              if (!check) {
                this.logoutService.logout();
                this.router.navigate(['login']);
              }
            });
          }
        });
  }
}
```

What's the best way for my interceptor to work well ?

Little update , here is how I check isNeedToRefresh

```
 get isNeedToRefresh(): boolean {
    const accessExpireTimestamp = new Date(
      localStorage.getItem('expires-at-access')
    ).getTime();
    const refreshExpireTimestamp = new Date(
      localStorage.getItem('expires-at-refresh')
    ).getTime();
    const nowTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
    if (nowTimestamp >= accessExpireTimestamp) {
      if (nowTimestamp >= refreshExpireTimestamp) {
        return null; // Refresh token expired
      } else {
        return true; // Refresh token not expired
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: On the first sight I don't see anything wrong (although I was looking only at the first two blocks). Try logging inside `if (res.access && res.refresh) {` just to check if your code even goes there.

Comment: @GytisTG yes it works , when I reload page. The issue that when session token time is over Interceptor doesn't know that he should use new token , he just takes value form localstorage. I need hard reload page to refresh token in localstorage or find another best way

Comment: I guess I need to refresh token in interceptor , but I dont know how yet

Comment: I checked again carefully and I'm now wondering how are you refreshing the value of `this.loginService.isNeedToRefresh === true`? Because if you don't refresh it after time is expired, this would evaluate to `false` and it wouldn't refresh on time, only on the second time.

Comment: @GytisTG I have updated my question. This method is described in login service

Comment: If you were to update your `isNeedToRefresh` to return always true, would that always send update token or no effect?

Comment: @GytisTG I've made `isNeedToRefresh` to return always true and it refreshes always when I reload page or go to next link inside my app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222951/discussion-between-gytis-tg-and-aidos-omurzakov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This desicion is worked for me , if someone else would meet such issue
I have fully re-writed my interceptor , basing on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57637923/angular-8-intercept-call-to-refresh-token)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoginService } from '../services/login.service';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, take, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  private refreshTokenInProgress = false;
  private refreshTokenSubject: Subject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  constructor(public loginService: LoginService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (request.url.indexOf('refresh') !== -1) {
      return next.handle(request);
    }

    const accessExpired = this.loginService.accessExpired;
    const refreshExpired = this.loginService.refreshExpired;

    if (accessExpired && refreshExpired) {
      return next.handle(request);
    }
    if (accessExpired && !refreshExpired) {
      if (!this.refreshTokenInProgress) {
        this.refreshTokenInProgress = true;
        this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);
        return this.loginService.refresh().pipe(
          switchMap((authResponse) => {
            console.log('authResponse ', authResponse)
            if (authResponse) {
              const token = localStorage.getItem('access-token');
              this.refreshTokenInProgress = false;
              this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token);
              return next.handle(this.injectToken(request));
            } else {
              return next.handle(request);
            }
          }),
        );
      } else {
        return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
          filter(result => result !== null),
          take(1),
          switchMap((res) => {
            return next.handle(this.injectToken(request))
          })
        );
      }
    }

    if (!accessExpired) {
      return next.handle(this.injectToken(request));
    }
  }

  injectToken(request: HttpRequest<any>) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('access-token');
    return request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });
  }
}
```